How to make a new colored block in a beamer poster?
I am using Gemini beamer poster template from GitHub, which has some nice options for alerted and example blocks. I tried to add a new qr block by editing the beamerthemegemini.sty file, but I am not sure why I am getting the error "Environment qrblock undefined".
Here is the edit I made in the style file:
% QR Block
\setbeamertemplate{block qr begin}
{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=0ex,dp=2ex,center]{block qr title}
    \vskip0pt
    \usebeamerfont{block title}\insertblocktitle
    \vskip-1.25ex
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=0.025ex]{block qr separator}\end{beamercolorbox}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  {\parskip0pt\par}
  \usebeamerfont{block body}
  \vskip-0.5ex
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=0ex]{block qr body}
  \justifying
  \begin{adjustwidth}{1ex}{1ex}
  \setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
  \vskip-2ex
}
\setbeamertemplate{block qr end}
{
  \end{adjustwidth}
  \vskip1ex
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vskip0pt
  \vspace*{2ex}
}


Can you please add a compilable test file to your question?

% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{gemini}
\usecolortheme{gemini}

\setbeamercolor{block qr title}{bg=red,fg=green}
\setbeamercolor{block qr body}{bg=orange,fg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{block qr separator}{bg=yellow}

  \newenvironment<>{qrblock}[1]{%
    \begin{actionenv}#2%
      \def\insertblocktitle{#1}%
      \par%
      \only<presentation>{%\usebeamerfont{block}%
        \setbeamercolor{local structure}{parent=qr text}}%
      \usebeamertemplate{block qr begin}}
    {\par%
      \usebeamertemplate{block qr end}%
    \end{actionenv}}

\setbeamertemplate{block qr begin}
{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=0ex,dp=2ex,center]{block qr title}
    \vskip0pt
    \usebeamerfont{block title}\insertblocktitle
    \vskip-1.25ex
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=0.025ex]{block qr separator}\end{beamercolorbox}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  {\parskip0pt\par}
  \usebeamerfont{block body}
  \vskip-0.5ex
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=0ex]{block qr body}
  \justifying
  \begin{adjustwidth}{1ex}{1ex}
  \setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
  \vskip-2ex
}
\setbeamertemplate{block qr end}
{
  \end{adjustwidth}
  \vskip1ex
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vskip0pt
  \vspace*{2ex}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
  \begin{block}{A block title}
  test
  \end{block}
  \begin{alertblock}{A block title}
  test
  \end{alertblock}
  \begin{qrblock}{A block title}
  test
  \end{qrblock}  
\end{frame}

\end{document}



Thank you for the quick response!
